# Do Sodium Alkynides react with esters in the same way that Grignard reagents do?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, organometallic-compounds

We know that Sodium alkynides react with aldehydes and ketones like Grignard reagents. But do they behave the same way with esters?

Comment: I no longer have Scifinder access but I can find very few references to the alkynation of esters and the few possible refer to lithium alkynides.

Comment: Okay,  I guess they dont.

Comment: I don't see why they would not, but they just don't appear to have been used.

Comment: I'm not sure though. Grignard reagents are way stronger right?

Comment: I don't know about way stronger. I would not use sodium acetylide in ethyl acetate.

Comment: I don't understand. Why is that?

Comment: I think it would react